# start url head changed after modified scrapy to scrapy-redis

Tags: scrapy, header

I have a scrapy project and I want to modified it to scrapy-redis:
the main scrapy file was below:

```
class MySpider(RedisSpider):
    name = 'ScrapyBot'
    redis_key = 'myspider:start_urls'
    start_urls = []

    my_header = {
        "Host": "jd.com",
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",
    }

def start_requests(self):
    for url in MySpider.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(
                            url=url,
                            headers=MySpider.my_header,
                            callback=self.parse}
                            )
```

the request works fine in Scrapy, but after add scrapy-redis part, header in start request(catched from Fidder) changed to default

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en
User-Agent: Scrapy/1.6.0 (+https://scrapy.org)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

which caused server returns 403 error, how can I fix the header for start urls in scrapy-redis?

Answer (score 0):

[You can set default headers](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#default-request-headers) in `settings.py` file this way:

```
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
    "Host": "jd.com",
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",
}
```